# How to train my own custom word embedding on web pages?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp

I have tons of text data on multiple web pages about the product I am interested to sell to customers. I tried using pre-trained fasttext word embedding trained on Wikipedia and it didn't give me good results for the classification task. Probably because the text data on the website contains lots of technical details and its different from text data in wikipedia. So I would like to do some kind of transfer learning of word embedding keeping the pretrained fasttext word embedding as base.

1. How can I train my own custom word embedding on these web pages using Keras?
2. How can I initialize the custom word embedding with fasttext pre-trained embedding and train? Will this initialization really help in giving better word embedding?

I would prefer a solution using Keras for training the word embedding.
I know Embedding has trainable=True option not sure how I can use it.

```
Embedding(voc_size, emb_dim, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length, trainable=True)
```

Which framework due to recommend for this Keras or Gensim and why?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that you use the gensim implementation of fastText to train your own word embeddings. This should be much easier and faster than your own Keras implementation. You can start by loading a pretrained model and then continue training with your own data.

```
from gensim.models import FastText

model = FastText.load_fasttext_format('cc.en.300.bin')

data = [['Hello', 'world'], ...] # Your own training data, a list of sentences
model.build_vocab(data, update=True)
model.train(sentences=data, 
            total_examples=model.corpus_count,
            epochs=5)
```

**EDIT:** If you want to implement your own model in Keras you can indeed use the Embedding layer with `trainable = True` (the default behaviour) as you suggest. [There is a good guide on how to do this here](https://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/word2vec-keras-tutorial/).

Comment: +1 so this code is actually updating the weights of the pretrained fasttext embedding based on the new training data?

Comment: Yes exactly. You can also try training your own model from scratch if you have a lot of data.

Comment: Do you mean to say Keras by default doesnt have simillar functionaly for training custom word embedding unless i develop my own implementation using tensorlfow? Why doesn't Embeddin(trainable=True) work?

Comment: Keras also works with the Embedding layer that you suggest. However, you need more preprocessing of your data since you cannot just pass in a list of words as you can in Gensim. You would need to encode each word as an integer index. Moreover, you would need to make word pairs that share the same context as well as random pairs and then make a classifier on top of your embedding layer that can tell the difference. I have tried to train my own embeddings with both Keras and Gensim and the Gensim implementation was way faster and actually also gave better embeddings in my case.

Comment: Cool. What happens if my new training data has new word thats not there in pretrained word embedding? How can I get word embedding for those new word embeddings?

Comment: I think that is covered by the line `model.build_vocab(data, update=True)`. But I haven't actually tried this myself, I have only tried training from scratch.

Comment: By the way, I have added a link to my answer with a guide on how to train your own word embeddings in Keras.

Answer (score 1):

1. To train only you must put the trainable flag to True in the Embedding layer. But he will train from the start-
2. To initialize the matrix you can use the one you consider, you have
   an example here:
   https://www.kaggle.com/lystdo/lstm-with-word2vec-embeddings (where
   the Google300Negatives is used and also only words are taken that
   they are used from the original matrix). Use weights parameter in Embedding constructor class (weights=[...]). This matrix should be the size of number of words x number of dimensions of the embedding.

In Keras any layer that has parameters can be trainable or not. 
This flag is useful when you only want to train a subset of layers (only fully-connected, etc) in order to avoid parameter exploding.

When you set as **trainable=true**:

- If the layer is in the middle of the network this only propagate
  input gradient but not correct any weight.
- If the layer is the first one of the network this not propagate any gradient.

In Embedding layer case you can initialize this layer as a default embedding matrix (gensim Gooogle300Negative for instance).

When you activate the trainable in this layer you are giving carte blanche for Keras to adjust as you consider this embedding. This also means having to optimize many more parameters.

There are cases in which there is no interest in modifying the initial embedding, either because of the cost involved or because it is to be conserved.

**EDIT:**
This task corresponds to the Tensorflow inside Keras. But this principle does not depend on the framework but only on the theory.
 
When you define a trainable = false, you are indicating that the weights should not be updated.

That means that intermediate layers must only calculate the gradient with respect to the input because the one of the weights is useless (just if they are calculated, nothing is gained and the trainable flag would not exist). They calculate with respect to the entrance because the gradient must continue propagating.

The first layer also has the particularity that the input is your data and therefore it is not necessary to continue propagating, therefore if the trainable = false you do not have to do anything.

In Tensorflow the trainable flag adds or not the variable to GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES collection, that way they are taken into account or not. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/trainable_variables

Comment: Could you elaborate the below "When you set as trainable=true:

If the layer is in the middle of the network this only propagate input gradient but not correct any weight.
If the layer is the first one of the network this not propagate any gradient."

Comment: Is there any keras documentation supporting this rule?

Comment: I have updated the answer. If you notice the behavior in both cases is the same, the first layer never propagates to the input (it is useless and a cost in calculating a derivative that will never be used).